# Creating a Windows forms app with database

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using 2010 ultimate and just build a simple windows forms application. Just added a database as well to the form. Pull the application file out of bin directory. Tried to run but got error as unable to attach database? Installed Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 and got same error? What am i dong wrong?

Error:
An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C;\Users\Admin\Desktop\Database1.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share

Comment: Add more details. What is the error you get?

Comment: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C;\Users\Admin\Desktop\Database1.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share

Comment: Please post your connection string from the application config file.

Comment: Did you pull the application file from bin directory *with* your config file?

Comment: Just moved the database1 primary data file to desktop and first time  there was a timeout error but second time it ran. This form is part of my project so to demonstrate on any computer and hence to be used on any machine, that machine needs net 3.5?, the application file, the database primary data file. Do i need also the transaction log file? Finally would i need to run also Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 in case to SQl server is not installed?

Comment: You can create the Installer for your appliction http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983326(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason i am getting a error is because i was trying to run the app file without the database in the same folder, in this case the desktop. I am currently trying to rectify this. I think i will go with a ado.net entity database online and forget integrating a local database with the desktop application. –

Answer (score 0):

Use `C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Database1.mdf` instead of `C;\Users\Admin\Desktop\Database1.mdf`

Comment: It is already that. I directly typed out the error from the alert box

Comment: Is there a `Database1.mdf` file in the directory `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\`?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="WindowsFormsApplication4.Properties.Settings.Database1ConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>

Comment: In what folder is your `Database1.mdf`?

Comment: The reason i am getting a error is because i was trying to run the app file without the database in the same folder, in this case the desktop. I am currently trying to rectify this. I think i will go with a ado.net entity database online and forget integrating a local database with the desktop application.